# Optimizing auto-import in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio

For example, when I am trying to implement `OnTouchListener`, Android Studio would automatically add:

```
import android.view.View;
```

Instead of:

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListner;
```

Those my implement line looks like:

```
public interface TouchHandler extends View.OnTouchListener {
```

Is there any way to make auto-import cut View and put just OnTouchListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports -> ensure that you have checked **"use single class import"**